# Python socket multiple connections

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to do python application which is connected with another java program and raspebrry pi. My program should constantly listen from java and raspberry and be able to response. I don't know how to do that. I'm using a couple of threads and I can send message to raspberry and listen java in the same time but I can't listen two connections and it's necessary for me.

```
def startProgram(sock):
try:
    sock.setblocking(False)
    sock.settimeout(10)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.connect((JAVA_HOST, JAVA_PORT))

    data = sock.recv(1024)

    if (data == "abc\r\n"):
         sock.sendall("abc otrzymane!!!\n")
         global ROBOT_IP_ADDRESS
         ROBOT_IP_ADDRESS = sys.argv[0] + "." + sys.argv[1] + "." + sys.argv[2] + "." + sys.argv[3]
         threading.Thread(target=Steering, args=[order]).start()
         threading.Thread(target=GetDistance, args=[sock]).start()
except:
    sock.close()
finally:
    return sock

//program starts here!
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = startProgram(sock)
sock.listen(1)
sock.setblocking(0)

while 1:
  conn, addr = sock.accept()
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  if (data == "camera\r\n"):
    isCameraOn = ~isCameraOn
    if isCameraOn == True:
        SendOrder("camera_on")
    else:
        SendOrder("camera_off")
  if(data == "order\r\n"):
    order = data
```

It's a code which is executed when I run this program from java. And it's code of function which is listening information from raspberry:

```
def GetDistance(s):
 s.bind((MY_IP_ADDRESS, FROM_ROBOT_PORT)) // EXCEPTION
 s.listen(1)
 while (True):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connection address:', addr)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE_DISTANCE)
        if not data: break
        print("received data:", data)
        conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
```

Generally problem is with socket. I can't create two socket variable and listen in different ports at the same time and I don't know why. Exception:

```
File "pythonScript.py", line 32, in GetDistance
   s.bind((JAVA_HOST, FROM_ROBOT_PORT))
File "<string>", line 1, in bind
File "C:\jython2.5.0\Lib\socket.py", line 777, in bind
  assert not self.sock_impl
AssertionError
```

I also don't know what exactly means this exception.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with java. Please remove the tag.

Comment: The error seems to say that s is not a socket. You might want to try s[0] instead?